# Adding custom text over an element returned by selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to locate elements on a webpage. I am using this code below to highlight the element and see where that element is on the page.

```
def highlight(element):
    driver = element._parent
    def apply_style(s):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, s)
    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    apply_style("background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")
    time.sleep(3)
    apply_style(original_style)
```

I found this on stackoverflow and it changes the background color of the given element to yellow for 3 seconds and then reverses back to the original state.

Now similarly I want to write a function that when given an element will write a small text over that element. Something like "Here's the element" or anything custom, over that element or adjacent to it to show me where the element has been found. 
Is there any way to do this by using javascript or any other way around to manipulate the web page like that ?

Comment: Is there any way this can be done with a CSS change or anything else ? I just need a custom text over an element on a webpage on my end.  Shouldnt be impossible right ?